# copy pdf into another folder in php

Tags: php, copy, fopen

I wanto to copy a pdf file to another folder, and it works, but the file that I open in the destination folder is decoded incorrectly and I can not open.
My code:

```
$fsrc = fopen($srcz,'r'); 
$fdest = fopen($destz,'w+');
copy($fsrc,$fdest)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
copy($srcz,$destz);
```

The copy function in PHP needs the source and destination. Consult the php manual: [Php copy](https://www.php.net/copy)

Comment: No, it's not. You are using `fopen`, not the source and destination of the file.

Comment: @BebPratzaBallus well, that's not what you said, in the code in your question you are passing the streams of the files and not the paths. (+1 to Codrutz btw)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that code you have works... see the function [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) takes the names of the files:

```
copy($srz,$destz);
```

If you want to copy the files opened with fopen you use [stream_copy_to_stream](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php), like so:

```
$fsrc = fopen($srcz,'r'); 
$fdest = fopen($destz,'w+');
stream_copy_to_stream($fsrc, $fdest);
fclose($fsrc);
fclose($fdest);
```

Do not forget to close the files!

Answer (score 0):

you should use copy without using fopen because fopen create a resource and copy too .

```
 $old = '/tmp/yesterday.txt';
 $new = '/tmp/today.txt';
 copy($old, $new) or die("Unable to copy $old to $new.");
```